# Fetched Saved CoreData Automatically in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, load, fetch

At the moment, the current Swift code allow me to save and load data.  However, instead of loading the data by clicking the load button, how do you load the data automatically in the field without clicking the btnLoad?

I want the data to retrieve and automatically fill in the UITextfield through CoreData once it has been saved.  By doing so, I won't need the btnLoad option.

```
@IBAction func btnSave() {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newUser.setValue(name.text, forKey: "name")
        newUser.setValue(phone.text, forKey: "phone")

        context.save(nil)

        println(newUser)
        println("Object Saved")

    }

    @IBAction func btnLoad() {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name.text)

        var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]!

        if(results.count > 0) {
            var res = results[0] as NSManagedObject
            name.text = res.valueForKey("name") as String
            phone.text = res.valueForKey("phone") as String

        } else {
            println("0 Results Returned... Potential Error")
        }
```

Comment: Does calling `btnLoad()`  after `context.save(nil)` respond to your question?

Comment: Try it but it doesn't work.

Comment: At first try capturing the error when you save. It might be that you have some problem saving.

Comment: I can save the load up the information as we speak.  However, the current coding force you to type in name first before the data can be loaded.